# in Talend - how to add tables into MySQL

Tags: mysql, etl, talend

I have a number of CSV files that I need to import into my Data warehouse. Since the csv files' columns may change every day, I decided to drop the old table and create a new table for each CSV file everyday. I'd prefer to do this using Talend jobs. I'd appreciate if someone tells me how to drop tables or create new tables in MySQL using Talend jobs?

Comment: What do you mean by csv columns are changing? Like is there any change in number of column or sequence of column or just column name are getting changed?

Comment: This is indeed problematic, since at some point you'll need a reliable schema. You can also do this in tMySQLOutput per default, I just think it is not very helpful to solve the underlying problem - the schema changes. Do you have any control about the schema you could demand as requirements? Even a report wouldn't work with a ever changing schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tmysqlrow to create and drop table in mysql using talend